# Scrapy Python script gives raise TypeError("Cannot mix str and non-str arguments")

Tags: python, string, xpath, scrapy, scrape

Hi I am new to programming and am running into this seemingly extremly common problem but honestly none of the answers I have seen helped me in my case.

My code is:

```
import json
import scrapy

class MoreKeysSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'getoffers'

    def __init__(self):
        with open(r'C:\Users\magnu\brickset-scraper\postscrape\postscrape\prod.json', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
            self.data = json.load(data_file)

    def start_requests(self):
        for item in self.data:
            request = scrapy.Request(item['url'], callback=self.parse)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parse(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['details'] = []


        item['details'].append({
            "Name" : response.css('span[itemprop=name]::text').extract_first(),
            "Release" : response.xpath('//*[@id="info"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/text()').extract_first(),
            "Website" : response.xpath('//*[@id="info"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/a/@href').extract_first(),
            "Entwickler" : response.xpath('//*[@id="info"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/text()').extract_first(),
            "Publisher" : response.xpath('//*[@id="info"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/text()').extract_first(),
            "Tags" : response.xpath('//*[@id="info"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/descendant').getall(),
            "Systemanforderungenmin" : response.xpath('//*[@id="config"]/ul[1]/descendant').getall(),
            "Systemanforderungenmax" : response.xpath('//*[@id="config"]/ul[2]/descendant').getall(),
            })
        yield item


        item['offer'] = []
        for div in response.css('#offers_table'):
            for offer_row in div.css('div.offers-table-row'):
                url = response.urljoin(offer_row.css('div.buy-btn-cell a::attr(href)')).get(),
                url_str = ''.join(map(str, url))     #coverts list to str
                item['offer'].append({
                    "offer:"
                    "Shop": offer_row.css('div[itemprop ~= seller] div.offers-merchant::attr(title)').extract_first(),
                    "Typ": offer_row.css('div.offers-edition-region::text').extract_first(),
                    "Edition": offer_row.css("div[data-toggle=tooltip]::attr(data-content)"),
                    "Link": response.follow(url_str, self.parse_topics),
                    })
                yield item
```

As a response I get

```
    DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.keyforsteam.de/kaufen-crusader-kings-2-cd-key-preisvergleich/>
{'url': 'https://www.keyforsteam.de/kaufen-crusader-kings-2-cd-key-preisvergleich/', 'details': [{'Name': '\n\t\t\t\t\tCrusader Kings 2\n\t\t\t\t', 'Release': '\n                                                    14. Februar 2012\n                            ', 'Website': 'https://www.paradoxplaza.com/crusader-kings-ii/CKCK02GSK-MASTER.html', 'Entwickler': '\n                                                    Paradox Development Studio\n
       ', 'Publisher': '\n                                                    Paradox Interactive\n
           ', 'Tags': [], 'Systemanforderungenmin': [], 'Systemanforderungenmax': []}]}
2021-03-22 21:47:22 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.keyforsteam.de/kaufen-crusader-kings-2-cd-key-preisvergleich/> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\magnu\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 120, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "c:\users\magnu\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "c:\users\magnu\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "c:\users\magnu\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\magnu\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "c:\users\magnu\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\magnu\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 340, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "c:\users\magnu\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\magnu\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\users\magnu\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "c:\users\magnu\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", 
line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "c:\users\magnu\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 62, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "C:\Users\magnu\brickset-scraper\postscrape\postscrape\spiders\keysint.py", line 40, in parse
    url = response.urljoin(offer_row.css('div.buy-btn-cell a::attr(href)')).get(),
  File "c:\users\magnu\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\response\text.py", line 
102, in urljoin
    return urljoin(get_base_url(self), url)
  File "c:\users\magnu\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 524, in urljoin
    base, url, _coerce_result = _coerce_args(base, url)
  File "c:\users\magnu\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 122, in _coerce_args       
    raise TypeError("Cannot mix str and non-str arguments")
TypeError: Cannot mix str and non-str arguments
```

So the first part seemingly works and I am pretty sure the mistake is somewhere in the second item, but I cant seem to find it

```
item['offer'] = []
        for div in response.css('#offers_table'):
            for offer_row in div.css('div.offers-table-row'):
                url = response.urljoin(offer_row.css('div.buy-btn-cell a::attr(href)')).get(),
                url_str = ''.join(map(str, url))     #coverts list to str
                item['offer'].append({
                    "offer:"
                    "Shop": offer_row.css('div[itemprop ~= seller] div.offers-merchant::attr(title)').extract_first(),
                    "Typ": offer_row.css('div.offers-edition-region::text').extract_first(),
                    "Edition": offer_row.css("div[data-toggle=tooltip]::attr(data-content)"),
                    "Link": response.follow(url_str, self.parse_topics),
                    })
                yield item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had kind of a circular route to get this one, but I think the debugging process would be instructive.

It's tougher to diagnose this without the json file the program is calling, but it looks like your problem is on this line: `url = response.urljoin(offer_row.css('div.buy-btn-cell a::attr(href)')).get(),`

From [How Can I Fix "TypeError: Cannot mix str and non-str arguments"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47507835/how-can-i-fix-typeerror-cannot-mix-str-and-non-str-arguments)

> According to the Scrapy documentation, the .css(selector) method that you're using, returns a SelectorList instance. If you want the actual (unicode) string version of the url, call the extract() method:

So I tried:

`url = response.urljoin(offer_row.css('div.buy-btn-cell a::attr(href)').extract()).get(),`

But I still get the same error. Strange!

To diagnose, I dropped a `breakpoint()` into the spider here:

```
        for div in response.css('#offers_table'):
            for offer_row in div.css('div.offers-table-row'):
                breakpoint()
                url = response.urljoin(offer_row.css('div.buy-btn-cell a::attr(href)').extract()).get(),
```

Running the spider again, I can test pieces of the next line:

```
(Pdb) offer_row.css('div.buy-btn-cell a::attr(href)').extract()
['https://www.keyforsteam.de/outgoinglink/keyforsteam/37370?merchant=1', 'https://www.keyforsteam.de/outgoinglink/keyforsteam/37370?merchant=1']
```

Ah, so `extract()` is giving back a list of strings rather than a single string. There must be two elements matching. However, they are identical, so we don't care which one we get. Looking at the scrapy docs at https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html, we see there's also an `extract-first()` function.

`url = response.urljoin(offer_row.css('div.buy-btn-cell a::attr(href)').extract-first()).get(),`

Although, looking at the scrapy docs, you probably want to use `get()` instead of `extract-first()`

Which is when I finally notice your only mistake was putting the `get()` outside the wrong set of parenthesis.

`url = response.urljoin(offer_row.css('div.buy-btn-cell a::attr(href)').get())`

Comment: Thanks so much was looking at this for ages not finding my mistake